# How do I send my form information, on submit, to my email with emailjs?

Tags: javascript, forms, email

I'm working on my project and I have a form that you fill out your name and email and then press submit. So far so good. The problem is that I'm trying to when the user presses "submit" the information that was filled in the form (name and email) go to my personal email. I'm currently using Emailjs because it was recomended by my school, but it's not working and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Here's what I've done so far:

```
//I put this is the end of the <head> section

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.emailjs.com/sdk/2.2.4/email.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            emailjs.init("user_"); //it has my user ID, just didn't want to share
        })();
</script>

//this is the form

<form id="testform" onsubmit="return sendMail(this);">
           <div class="box">
                 <label for="fullname" class="form-tag">Name</label>
                 <input type="text" name="name" id="fullname" class="form-control" required/>
                 <label for="emailaddress" class="form-tag">Email</label>
                 <input type="email" name="email" id="emailaddress" class="form-control" required/>
                 <div class="button">
                   <button id="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-lg">Submit</button>
                 </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

//and this is right before the end of the

```
<script src="assets/js/sendEmail.js"></script>
```

//the sendEmail.js

```
function sendMail(contactForm) {
    emailjs.send("gmail", "yourjourney", {
        "from_name": contactForm.name.value,
        "from_email": contactForm.emailaddress.value,
    })
    .then(
        function(response) {
            console.log("SUCCESS", response);
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log("FAILED", error);
        }
    );
    return false;  // To block from loading a new page
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @elnatanvazana I don't get an error. But I don't get an email either.

Answer (score 1):

so you have two issues in your code.
First your button is type button beside type submit.
Second you are using return false which means you stop the submitting proccess.

for you to be able to make it work without the page reloading you don't have to create a form.
It will be a bit different than what the school teaches you, but i hope it will help.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emailjs-com@2/dist/email.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        (function () {
            emailjs.init('user_ID');
        })();
    </script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <label for="fullname" class="form-tag">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="fullname" class="form-control" required />
        <label for="emailaddress" class="form-tag">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="emailaddress" class="form-control" required />
        <div class="button">
            <button id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-lg">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="assets/js/sendEmail.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS (sendEmail.js file):

```
//Getting the name and email from the DOM
let fullName = document.getElementById('fullname').value
let email = document.getElementById('emailaddress').value
//Getting the button from the DOM
let submitButton = document.getElementById('button') 

//Add event listener on click to the button - notice i added the event as argument to the function
submitButton.addEventListener('click', function(event){

    //prevent the reload of the page. here i prevent the event.
    event.preventDefault()

    //Sending the email with the name and email
    emailjs.send("gmail", "yourjourney", {
        "from_name": fullName,
        "from_email": email,
    })
        .then(
            function (response) {
                console.log("SUCCESS", response);
                
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log("FAILED", error);
                
            }

        );
})
```

If you must have the form and its part of homework or something let me know so i can change the code according to what you are learning.

Comment: I get this in the console:

sendEmail.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).addEventListener is not a function
    at sendEmail.js:8

Comment: I edited the answer. please copy paste the same code to the HTML and the js code to the sendEmail.js file and tell me if its still gives and error. don't forget to change USER_ID in the HTML head function

Answer (score 0):

```
//Getting the button from the DOM
let submitButton = document.getElementById('button') 

//Add event listener on click to the button - notice i added the event as argument to the function
submit.addEventListener('click', function(event){

    //prevent the reload of the page. here i prevent the event.
    event.preventDefault()

    //Getting the name and email from the DOM
    let fullName = document.getElementById('fullname').value
    let email = document.getElementById('emailaddress').value

    //Sending the email with the name and email
    emailjs.send("gmail", "yourjourney", {
        "from_name": fullName,
        "from_email": email,
    })
        .then(
            function (response) {
                console.log("SUCCESS", response);
                
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log("FAILED", error);
                
            }

        );
})
```

1. Thank you @elnatan vazana for helping me!
2. My user ID was incorrect, so I changed it and now it workd fine. I'm able to receive the information that is submitted to the form.

Comment: your welcome. if my answer helped you it will be great if you will chose it as the answer to your question (but marking the V next to the answer). im glad it ts working good luck with your coding journy.